# How to hide elements with css using checkboxes: different outputs according to element id or class?

Tags: css

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/9/) that should show and hide element outputs according to specific checkboxes.

The output that I´ve got is that each checkbox, when clicked, shows more outputs than it should.

How can they be targeted using specific css IDs?

I mean, whan you click on each box, it should only appear the text that´s referencin that specific box, and not all of them.

Thanks for your insight!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/10/)

```
/*styled relative to the label*/
label {display:block;}
label ~ div {display:none; margin-left:1em;}

/*targetting*/
/*boxes with id having this number will style a sibling div with this number*/
input[type="checkbox"][id*="131"]:checked ~ div[class*="131"] {display:inline;}
input[type="checkbox"][id*="134"]:checked ~ div[class*="134"] {display:inline;}
input[type="checkbox"][id*="130"]:checked ~ div[class*="130"] {display:inline;}
```

Comment: General sibling combinator. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contains `*=` selector. I'm not sure what browser compatibility it has, but it works for me in Chrome. For instance changing the CSS for the first of the three checkboxes looks like this:

```
input[id*="131"]:checked ~ div[class="tipo-uf-131"] {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close to a perfect example of overthinking things and relying too heavily on CSS. Stylesheets are supposed to be in charge of *presentation* not *functionality*. CSS selectors can be complex enough that you could use it for validation checks - does not make it a good idea though :)

You're much better off relying on javascript to accomplish this and would end up with a significantly wider browser support matrix. Change your markup a bit:

```
<label>Box 1:</label> <input class="form-checkbox" id="cb131" type="checkbox"/>
...<input class="form-checkbox" id="cb134" type="checkbox"/>
...<input class="form-checkbox" id="cb130" type="checkbox"/>
<div id="cb131-linked"><b>Box 1 is checked.</b></div>
<div id="cb134-linked">...</div>
<div id="cb130-linked">...</div>
```

​...and you can add a jQuery listener so that when the state of a checkbox is toggled, you can show the related divs like so:

```
$checkboxes = $(".form-checkbox");
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    console.log("changed");
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        $this = $(this)
        $("#"+$this.attr("id")+"-linked").toggle($this.is(":checked"));
    });
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/11/

Also, inputs are supposed to be self-closing elements.